# Is there a way that I can make a collection within a document in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I am trying to see if it is possible to put a collection that can be referenced from a document in mongodb

The goal would be to be able to reference data like this.

users -> user123 -> groups -> group123

Are there any docs that could help me with this please and thank you

Comment: I think you are looking for this: [MongoDB Data Modeling - Intro](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/). _Also_, you can search the net (using Google, etc.) for more information using  a search string like "mongodb data modeling best practices" _or_ "moongodb database design".

Comment: @prasad_ thank you that was the answer to my question